# flutterの画像　エラー

Tags: 画像, flutter, chrome-extension

flutterのchromeで実行をできていたのですが、画像を入れた途端に実行ができなくなり
cannot launch without an active deviceと表示されます。
何回かやり直しましたが、必ず画像を表示する段階でエラーが起こります。何が原因かお分かりの方ご教授ください。よろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: > 画像を入れた途端に とは、具体的にどのような操作を行いましたか？

Answer (score 0):

VSCodeを使っている場合、右下の`device`のところをチェックしてみてください、もし`chrome`が接続可能であれば`device`をクリックすると`chrome`の選択肢が出てくるはずです。

`device`をクリックしても`chrome`もし出ていない場合はVSCodeを再起動してみてください（VSCodeの全部のウィンドウを閉じる必要があります）。 それでもできない場合はChromeのコアの設定を調べてみてください。